# Adding and handling custom settings tab to fusion element

Tags: plugin-development, themes

I'm developing an add on that wraps standard fusion shortcode around content coming from webservices calls.

By now I created 3 or 4 custom components whose option panel embed the corresponding short code parameters input section and pass those arguments "under the hood" the original fusion shortcode.

I'm conscious that this approach is not the cleanest and shows its limits when i try to use it on Fusion_container elements.

So my question is: is it possible to inject a custom settings group inside existing elements?

I'd like to add the "My Custom Settings" (in the screenshot is just a mock done in Chrome):

[image]

Second question, if this is possible, how can I then handle custom parameters inected? to be more specific: i'd like to render fusion Container only if some conditions are met.

Thanks!

Comment: You better contact with ThemeFusion support, they have dedicated team from this.

Comment: thank @obiPlabon, before opening a ticket I'm trying to see if any other user has ever stumbled upon something like that ;)